# MySQL JSON search for value inside array

Tags: mysql, json

JSON:

```
{
  "type1": [
    "gI7TyvfUJfdhY1e8HClmqcLprhRxFJcAoqMig2A3",
    "AKCbwJ4KOLpQw1wLAcx5Qxwm2q9ntDPeM0wgLBO8"
  ],
  "type2": [
    "M3CDgTUx7UXSv0nj1pRSHf8gqLrJv4nMEP0l0A7X"
  ]
}
```

Table structure:

```
id, name, types
```

How can i search json field "types" to search for given string "M3CDgTUx7UXSv0nj1pRSHf8gqLrJv4nMEP0l0A7X"

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(types, '$.*') FROM person where types is not null and JSON_EXTRACT(types, '$.*') like "%M3CDgTUx7UXSv0nj1pRSHf8gqLrJv4nMEP0l0A7X%"
```

I guess this query is not the best i could do.

Comment: What is your expected result? the value you are searching for, or the entire `types` value?

Comment: just row filtered by value in any array typeX in json

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) to look for `types` values that contain a particular string, checking that the result is not `NULL` (indicating a match):

```
SELECT *
FROM person 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(types, 'one', '%M3CDgTUx7UXSv0nj1pRSHf8gqLrJv4nMEP0l0A7X%') IS NOT NULL
```

If you want to get the specific matching value (for example when searching on a subset of the string), you can use [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) on the unquoted output of `JSON_SEARCH`:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(types, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(types, 'one', '%j1pRSHf8gqLrJ%')))
FROM person 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(types, 'one', '%j1pRSHf8gqLrJ%') IS NOT NULL
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dd4ea86c86b105c6ee71b882ad02bfc7)